# Visual Studio 2008 using incorrect version of mscorlib

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

A while back a project I'm working on (and all other projects in the solution) were switched over to .Net 3.5. I'm trying to make use of Guid.TryParse which rocked up in .Net 3.5. When I try to use it I get the error:

```
'System.Guid' does not contain a definition for 'TryParse'
```

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(VS.90).aspx) clearly show that TryParse exists in .Net 3.5, but I'm unable to use it. I tried manually referencing the specific version of mscorlib, but visual studio refused. What might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: The linked page says that it is available in .NET 4.

Comment: Odd, when I went there it looked like this: http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/4665/tryparse.png

Comment: And what did the "supported versions" bit say?

Comment: Yep, fair point. That's daft though, if you have a page stating specific to .Net 3.5 and a method description I think it's a fair assumption that it's supported in .Net 3.5 Ah well.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian's comment says, the docs "clearly show" that it's in .NET 4, not .NET 3.5.

> **Version information**
>
> **.NET Framework**
>   Supported in: 4
>   **.NET Framework Client Profile**
>   Supported in: 4

If you look in the [`Guid` methods in .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid_methods(v=VS.90).aspx) you'll see it's clearly not there.